# Output of error stack does not contain all info

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using [PnP SPFx API](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/error-handling/) in my project and I am dealing with error handling. In my code there are few API calls and I need to get a whole stack trace of the calls which were made so I can see where does the error come from.

I have also tried the Error object, `Error.captureStackTrace()` but obviously in Typescript it does NOT work.

Sample

```
  public async apiCallWrapper<T>(callback: ICallback<T>) : 
               Promise<[T, ResponseStatus, string]> {
    try {
      const result : T = await callback();
      return [result, ResponseStatus.Success, 'Success'];
    } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
    console.trace()
    return [null, ResponseStatus.Other, 'Other kind of error'];
  }
```

```
    >> console.log(e.stack)
    Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] Bad Request ::>
    {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":
    {"lang":"en-US","value":"Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."}}}
    at new HttpRequestError (https://localhost:4321/dist/sx-web-part.js:21243:28)
    at Function.<anonymous> (https://localhost:4321/dist/sx-web-part.js:21258:47)
    at step (https://localhost:4321/dist/sx-web-part.js:19733:23)
    at Object.next (https://localhost:4321/dist/sx-web-part.js:19714:53)
    at fulfilled (https://localhost:4321/dist/sx-web-part.js:19704:58)
```

```
    >> console.trace()
    overrideMethod  @   react_devtools_backend.js:2526
    (anonymous) @   BaseApi.ts:54
    step    @   sx-web-part.js:973
    (anonymous) @   sx-web-part.js:954
    fulfilled   @   sx-web-part.js:945
    Promise.then (async)        
    step    @   sx-web-part.js:947
    rejected    @   sx-web-part.js:946
    Promise.then (async)        
    step    @   sx-web-part.js:947
    (anonymous) @   sx-web-part.js:948
    0uds.__awaiter  @   sx-web-part.js:944
    0uds.BaseApi.apiCallWrapper @   BaseApi.ts:40
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public async apiCallWrapper<T>(callback: ICallback<T>) : 
           Promise<[T, ResponseStatus, string]> {
>> stack = getStack();
try {
  const result : T = await callback();
  return [result, ResponseStatus.Success, 'Success'];
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.stack) << stack here is not complete
  console.trace()
  return [null, ResponseStatus.Other, 'Other kind of error'];
} 

public getStack() {
  let stack = '';
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch(e) {
    stack = e.stack;
  }
  return stack;
}
```